# I want to find values greater than/less than a specific value In Google Sheets and replace them with a another value

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

[image]I have a have a data set in Google Sheets consisting of numbers between 1 and 100. I want to replace all numbers greater than 10, with 10 (or any other number I choose). Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Could you share an example sheet to check how you have the arrangement of numbers? Always try to include a [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that reproduces the issue.

Comment: Hi Gabriel, I've added a screenshot.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose your original numbers are in A2:A. Place the following formula in B2 of an otherwise empty range B2:B...

`=ArrayFormula(IF(A2:A="",, IF(A2:A<10, A2:A, 10)))`

For some other maximum number, just change the two instances of `10` in the formula to that other number.

Comment: Hi Erik, I've added a screenshot to show how my numbers are arranged. Would your formula work with this arrangement, and if so, how would I change the formula?

Comment: If you want to process those numbers in place (i.e., replace the existing numbers with new numbers), formulas will not work. You will need a script. If you don't mind the new numbers being rendered into the same range on a separate sheet then, yes, a formula would work. In that case, share a link to a sample spreadsheet and I'll take another look.